# Where is Cygwin set its PATH variable?

Tags: path, bashrc, cygwin

If I write `echo $PATH` in my Cygwin window (`mintty`) I get a list of paths. That list does not match the Windows Envirnonement variables list. I cannot find a file, where is the variable `$PATH` set. None of the `~/.*` files like `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.inputrc`, `.minttyrc` contain `$PATH` setting.
 So, where is the variable `$PATH` actually set?

Comment: there's [indications](https://github.com/mirror/newlib-cygwin/blob/17918cc6a6e6471162177a1125c6208ecce8a72e/newlib/libc/sys/linux/include/paths.h#L36) that the default path is "/usr/bin:/bin" -- is that what you're seeing?

Comment: there could be files like /etc/profile, but doesn't cygwin start with converting the DOS PATH variable?

Answer (score 4):

For bash the PATH is set initially in `/etc/profile`

```
  # Setup some default paths. Note that this order will allow user installed
  # software to override 'system' software.
  # Modifying these default path settings can be done in different ways.
  # To learn more about startup files, refer to your shell's man page.

  : ${ORIGINAL_PATH=${PATH}}
  if [ ${CYGWIN_NOWINPATH-addwinpath} = "addwinpath" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"
  else
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
  fi
```

By default it includes the Windows PATH

If you need to modify it the best place are `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html

The PATH is initially inherited from the Windows PATH environment variable with minor changes `\` character -> `/` character.

Consider modifying `/etc/profile` as the first best choice.

Before you do anything the very first time:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}
```

so you can access the cygwin UNIX tools. To set `/etc/profile` up as needed.